# I have Axios which returns 2 request from 2 controllers the second request does not return any data

Tags: vue.js, axios, laravel-7

this is the config Vue

```
import Api from './Api'
import Csrf from './Csrf'

export default {
     showProd(id) {
        return Api.get('/products/' + id)
    },
    showCat(){
        return Api.get('/products/category')
    },
    loadProds () {
        return Api.get('/products')
    }

}
```

this is what's inside the method: ()

```
showProd (id) { 
  Products.showProd(id).then((response) => {//this code works
    this.show1prod = response.data
    console.log(this.show1prod.product_name)
  })
  Products.showCat().then((responseCat) => {//this returns empty
    this.showCat = responseCat.data
    console.log(this.showCat.category_name)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    alert(error)
  })

}
```

this is my controller and api for the second request, I have both 200 status so I guess I'm, hitting the backend but the data is empty

```
Route::get('/products/category', 'ProductsCategoryController@category');

class ProductsCategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function category()
    {
        $category = ProductsCategory::all();
        return response()->json($category);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remove the second request and just move it in the mounted function and call this function whenever a row with id matches the record

```
    Products.showCat().then( data => {
      this.showCat = data.data
      // alert(this.showCat)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the order in which routes are defined in the backend.

You should define `products/category` **before** `products/{id}`
Otherwise when you call `products/category` the controller for `products/{id}` will be called with `id = 'category'`.

Maybe that is the issue for you.

Route ordering you should go for.

```
    Route::get('/products/category', 'ProductsCateogryController@category');

    Route::post('/products/{id}', 'BlahController@blah');

    Route::get('/products', 'BlahBlahController@blahBlah');
```

There will be issues if you define the routes in a different order.

You could add somekind of logging in your controllers to see which controller is actually being called.

```
    \Log::info('inside products');
    \Log::info('inside products/id');
    \Log::info('inside products/cateogry');
```

Comment: yeah well I also did that I already updated my code and instead of calling 2 methods I just mounted the show product and put it in a method

Comment: I meant in the laravel code's `routes/` folder. Your laravel routes files. Edited the answer.